# Identifying and matching non ascii characters in files

Tags: java, encoding, utf, non-ascii-characters

I'm trying to read a delimited file and parse its contents. Unlike a CSV, the delimiter, string qualifier etc are non ASCII ie. U0014 and U00FE respectively. However, I'm unable to detect the string qualifier character (FE) . Is this because the character's value is greater 128 or something else?

Here's a simple program that illustrates the core issue. How can I make this work? Here's a link to a very small test file . https://www.dropbox.com/s/1cilircwc3pq78c/nonascii.dat?dl=0

Thanks

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.LineIterator;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.Reader;

public class CharMatch {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {
    final String pathname = "/home/vinayb/Downloads/nonascii.dat";
    final File file = new File(pathname);
    final String encoding = "UTF-8";
    final PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, encoding);
    final Reader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(file), encoding));

    final LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file, encoding);
    try {
        //read a line
        final String line = it.nextLine();
        final char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
        for (char c : chars) {
            out.println(c + " , with decimal value: " + Character.getNumericValue(c) + " and hexa value: " + Integer.toHexString(Character.getNumericValue(c)));
        }

        out.println("------------------------------------");
        final String expectedDelimiter = fromUnicode("0014");
        final String expectedStringQualifier = fromUnicode("00FE");
        out.println("##### expected delimiter:" + expectedDelimiter);

        out.println("##### expected string qualifier:" + expectedStringQualifier);
        String[] items = line.split(expectedDelimiter);
        out.println("#### " + items.length + " " + items[0]);

        if (line.contains(expectedDelimiter)) {
            out.println("Found delimiter"); ////=======> can match this
        }

        if (line.contains(expectedStringQualifier)) {
            out.println("Found string qualifier"); //=======> can't match this
        }
    } finally {
        LineIterator.closeQuietly(it);
    }
}

private static String fromUnicode(String codePoint) {
    return "" + (char) Integer.parseInt(codePoint, 16);
}
```

}

Comment: "string qualifier character"? And what is that supposed to be?

Comment: It's a character used to qualify strings. A commonly used delimiter is a ". For  example in csv, we would use delimiters thus `"John Doe", "123, Main Street"` . In this case, the delimiter is 00FE . See  this link for what  it looks like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is not valid UTF-8:

```
$ iconv -f utf-8 *dat >/dev/null; echo $?
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0
1
```

But it can be "read" as ISO-8859-1:

```
$ iconv -f iso-8859-1 *dat >/dev/null; echo $?
0
```

Just change the encoding to that; but such a file format in 2015 is rather strange. What you should really do is ask the source of such files to live with the times ;)

Note that since the first sequence of bytes is not valid, by default Java will substitute it with [U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm); and it will do so with every byte sequence it cannot convert into `char`s. In order to have Java throw an exception even in this case, you will need to instantiate a `CharsetDecoder` (from a `Charset` instance) and specify that you want to `.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT)` (the default is `CodingErrorAction.REPLACE`).

Comment: I used the ISO-8859-1 format and that allowed me to read the files

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://codepoints.net/U+00FE?lang=en). 00 FE might be the right code for UTF-16 but in UTF-8 it's C3 BE. This might also explain why it's not valid UTF-8.